# How FAT (File Allocation Table) works?

Tags: fat32, fat16

I got the following description of FAT from a powerpoint slide:

```
Partition boot record(1 sector)
-------------------------------
Main FAT (size is up to 2 clusters)
-------------------------------
Backup FAT (sam size as main FAT)
-------------------------------
Root directory
-------------------------------
Data area(size varies)
```

By searching on the Internet, mainly I can  get the main point of FAT features. But getting into details like the above, I dont understand the functionality of each part as shown.

Can anyone explain features of each section in the above FAT structure?

Comment: A nice tip is to google "FAT32 specification"

Comment: Or read Wikipedia's article on FAT32: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT32#Technical_design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT_filesystem) has a good explanation:

> A FAT file system is composed of four different sections:
>
> The Reserved sectors, located at the very beginning. The first
>   reserved sector (sector 0) is the Boot Sector (aka Volume Boot Record
>   (VBR)). It includes an area called the BIOS Parameter Block (with some
>   basic file system information, in particular its type, and pointers to
>   the location of the other sections) and usually contains the operating
>   system's boot loader code. Important information from the Boot Sector
>   is accessible through an operating system structure called the Drive
>   Parameter Block (DPB) in DOS and OS/2. The total count of reserved
>   sectors is indicated by a field inside the Boot Sector. For FAT32 file
>   systems, the reserved sectors include a File System Information Sector
>   at sector 1 and a Backup Boot Sector at sector 6.
>
> The FAT Region.
>
> This typically contains two copies (may vary) of the File Allocation
>   Table for the sake of redundancy checking, although rarely used, even
>   by disk repair utilities. These are maps of the Data Region,
>   indicating which clusters are used by files and directories. In FAT12
>   and FAT16 they immediately follow the reserved sectors. Typically the
>   extra copies are kept in tight synchronization on writes, and on reads
>   they are only used when errors occur in the first FAT. In FAT32, it is
>   possible to switch from the default behaviour and select a single FAT
>   out of the available ones to be used for diagnosis purposes.
>
> The Root Directory Region.
>
> This is a Directory Table that stores information about the files and
>   directories located in the root directory. It is only used with FAT12
>   and FAT16, and imposes on the root directory a fixed maximum size
>   which is pre-allocated at creation of this volume. FAT32 stores the
>   root directory in the Data Region, along with files and other
>   directories, allowing it to grow without such a constraint. Thus, for
>   FAT32, the Data Region starts here.
>
> The Data Region.
>
> This is where the actual file and directory data is stored and takes
>   up most of the partition. Traditionally, the unused parts of the data
>   region are initialized with a filler value of 0xF6 during format on
>   IBM compatible machines, but also used on the Atari Portfolio. 8-inch
>   CP/M floppies typically came pre-formatted with a value of 0xE5;[9] by
>   way of Digital Research this value was also used on Atari ST formatted
>   floppies.[nb 3] Some modern formatters wipe hard disks with a value of
>   0x00, whereas a value of 0xFF is used on flash disks to reduce wear.
>   The latter value is typically also used on ROM disks. (Some advanced
>   formating tools allow to configure the format filler byte.[nb 4])
>
> The size of files and subdirectories can be increased arbitrarily (as
>   long as there are free clusters) by simply adding more links to the
>   file's chain in the FAT. Note however, that files are allocated in
>   units of clusters, so if a 1 KB file resides in a 32 KB cluster, 31 KB
>   are wasted.
>
> FAT32 typically commences the Root Directory Table in cluster number
>   2: the first cluster of the Data Region.